# Insert value in hidden field using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies, hidden-field

I have created a cookie using php. want to read it using javascript then want to submit cookie name using a hidden field to server.
So 
I want to insert cookie name in a hidden field using jquery.
That means if cookie created i want to insert cookie name into a hidden field.

so that url like this: localhost/backupimage/unlink.php?dirname=72-1394951508

what will be the right procedure.

```
    var x = document.cookie; 
    var n=x.split("=");
    if ((n.length > 0)){
       // alert(n[1]);
       $("#dirname").val(n[1]);
    }
<form action="unlink.php" id="removedata">

<input TYPE="submit" id="delvalue"  VALUE="Clear Data" />
<input TYPE="hidden" id="dirname" name="dirname" value=""/>
</form>
```

Comment: may I know what is your problem..?

Comment: Use `jquery.cookie` plugin to read cookie since you're still using jquery.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/r78XQR8m
http://pastebin.com/gzLvzHUW
http://pastebin.com/NRXCGKgt     a folder is created in to server when cookie is created using php. so i want to delete that folder when user want to clear data .

Comment: what was the output of `alert(n[1])`??

Comment: alert output 72-1394951508 and it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

name your form.

```
<form name="dirform" action="unlink.php" id="removedata">
```

and try:

```
document.dirform.dirname.value = n[1];
```